# Magento username/password incorrect. Password retrieval not working

Tags: password, table

Tried logging in today to my **Magento (localhost/magento/admin/)**

```
Password is incorrect.
```

Trying to use the password retrieval, I am not receiving the e-mail with the new password. Not in spam etc...

Attemped to changed the password in `phpadmin > magent > user_admin (something like that)`. Changed the password for my username, confirmed correct e-mail. Pressed go.

Still cannot login in.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 UPDATE admin_user SET password=CONCAT(MD5('qXpassword'), ':qX') WHERE username='admin';
```

See [Magento - Wiki - Resetting Admin Password](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/recover/resetting-admin-password)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **new Admin Account** using the below command form your terminal 
Go to your root directory of the **Magento** & run this command

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="123123q" --admin-email="admin@example.com" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="Admin"
```

This time remember your password to login into your account